# React router Validating DOM Nesting error

Tags: react-router

Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): `<a>` cannot appear as a descendant of `<a>`. See NavigationBar > a > ... > Link > a

```
<a className="ui item nav-logout font-color">
        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <Link onClick={this.logout} to="/" >
            Logout
          </Link>
        ) : (
          <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        )}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting a `<a>` tag into another `<a>` tag, change the parent to a `<div>`/`<span>` (or `<li>` if your nav items are in a list) :

```
<span className="ui item nav-logout font-color">
```

Answer (score 0):

this error is about too many rendering elements inside of the component.  so that try this command inside of the react fragment tag.

```
return(
<React.Fragment >

<a className="ui item nav-logout font-color">
        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <Link onClick={this.logout} to="/" >
            Logout
          </Link>
        ) : (
          <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        )}


</React.Fragment>
);
```